# Changing service account password via Powershell gives me error 1609 but password is correct

Tags: powershell, service

I've managed to write a PS script that changes the log on account and sets it to automatically start a service after the installation of that program. It also changes the password to a verified correct password but it will always fail to start the service. Going in and manually starting the service gives me a

> error 1609 the service did not start due to a log on failure

The only way to start the service is to go in and manually change the password (copy and pasting the same password that I use in the script), so I've ruled out having an incorrect password. Should I be changing the format of this script at all? It will change the service account and startup type correctly, but somehow the password is not going through.

This is the script:

```
$Svc = Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "name='[ServiceToStart]'"
$Svc.Change($Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$false,"service_account@domain.com","[redacted-password-obviously]")
Set-Service '[ServiceToStart]' -startuptype "Automatic"

Stop-Service -Name '[ServiceToStart]'
Start-Service -Name '[ServiceToStart]'
```

And this is the output response I get when I run it:

```
__GENUS : 2
__CLASS : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS : 
__DYNASTY : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION : {}
__SERVER : 
__NAMESPACE : 
__PATH : 
ReturnValue : 0
PSComputerName : 



Start-Service : Service '[ServiceToStart]([ServiceToStart])' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start 
service [ServiceToStart]on computer '.'.
At C:\Windows\TEMP\AeX_{A8E5BB25-CF2C-4C51-954D-57CECF38E971}_9936.ps1:6 char:1
+ Start-Service -Name '[ServiceToStart]'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], 
ServiceCommandException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really mean to use "account@domain.com" as the user? Usually you'd only need the account name.

Comment: Sorry, just redacted the specific name and domain. I've got the specific account name and domain required to log in to this application.